# Identifying the periodic function

Tags: functions

Which of the functions below is not periodic ?

a.) $e^{sinx}$

b.) $(10+sinx+cosx)^{-1}$

c.)$log(cosx)$

d.)$sin(e^x)$

My question - Although I could intuitively find out the answer to the following question , but I would like to know what is the mathematical approach to the following question .
In other words it would be very helpful if you could show me what is the period of choices a , b, and c ?

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of a periodic function?

Comment: I tried using f(x+p) = f(x).
But I think I failed to apply it properly . A little hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here goes. Let $f(x) = \log\cos(x)$. $f(x+2 k \pi) = \log\cos(x+2 k \pi) = \log\cos(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: One general point which perhaps captures your intuition: If $f(x)$ is periodic, then so is $g(f(x))$. In addition, the period of $g(f(x))$ can't be larger than that of $f(x)$ itself. It can be smaller, though: $f(x)=\sin x$ is $2\pi$-periodic, but composing it with $g(x)=x^2$ gives $g(f(x))=\sin^2 x$ which is $\pi$-periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin(x+2\pi)=\sin{x}$ for all $x$.

$\cos(x+2\pi)=\cos{x}$ for all $x$.

So the first three functions are all periodic, because they are functions of $\sin{x}$ and $\cos{x}$ only. They repeat when $x$ increases by $2\pi$, which implies that $2\pi$ is a multiple of the period of each of them. You can tell this *without looking at the details of the functions at all*. If you do look at the details of the functions, you'll see that in fact $2\pi$ *is* the period of each of them. Some other functions of $\sin{x}$ have a shorter period: for instance, $\sin ^2{x}$ has a period of $\frac12 2\pi$.

You could deduce that since the question asks "Which of the functions below is not periodic?", one of them must be not periodic, and only (d) is left. On the other hand, it is educational to check (d) as well.

Let's assume that (d) is periodic.

Let's put $y=e^x$. Then the function we are looking at is $\sin y$, and each step $p$ in $x$ is equivalent to multiplying $y$ by $e^p$.

1. $e^p$ must be an integer, because $y=\pi$ has to be transformed into a multiple of $\pi$ (since $\sin({e^p}y)$ has to be equal to $\sin y$, which is $0$).
2. Now try going backwards! If $y=\pi$, and we go back one step, we divide $y$ by the integer $e^p$, which gives us a non-integer multiple of $\pi$. But $\sin y$ can't equal $\sin\pi$ if $y$ is not an integer multiple of $\pi$.

This is a contradiction. So our assumption that (d) is periodic must be false.